# "if" condition is not working

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm working on a big project but here I am stucked on a little part of this one. The aim is to make a thing happen with 40% chance, so I make an array of 10 number which consists 4 "1" and 6 "0", if it randoms to "1" then it will happen but however my condition is not working, it always print "abcd" even if it randoms "0". Are there any dumb mistakes in here?
The second counter part is to make it happens once every 3 seconds

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include "vtscreen.h"


int main(void){
int x, y, i=0;
int random1, random2, min;
int array[10] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0};

srand(time(NULL));

//ClearScreen();

time_t start, end;
int elapsed;

time(&start);  /* start the timer */


do {
    time(&end);

    elapsed = difftime(end, start);
    //gotoxy(1, 15);
    printf("Time elapsed: %.1d\n", elapsed);
    if(elapsed == 0) continue;
    min = elapsed%3;
    if(min == 0){
        random1 = array[rand() % 10];
        printf("%d\n", random1);
            if(random1 == 1){
                printf("abcd");
            }
    }
} 
while (1);

}
```

This is the condition part that I'm stucked

```
printf("%d\n", random1);
            if(random1 == 1){
                printf("abcd");
            }
```

UPDATE:
So I just try to make condition as "random1 == 2" and it 's not working, it seems that when the random 's running, even the result is "0", if it randoms through "1" the condition 's still working. Are there anyways to make a condition with random number or any solution for 40% chance?

Comment: What's the exact output?

Comment: in this case I just printf("abcd") to simplize thing

Comment: Where is `random1` declared?

Comment: What is `min`?  Please give us a complete program we can compile and run.

Comment: Oops sorry, okay guys here 's the full one

Comment: `rand() % 9` gives a number between 0 and 8.

Comment: unclear what you're asking Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Your timing logic will re-roll and print many times between 3 and 4 seconds, then again between 6 and 7 seconds and so on. Some of these rolls will saitsfy your condition, so that you see "abcd" printed. (You never overwrite that in the contrary case.) That's probably not what you want. You could reset your `start` time after printing, for example. Or use a real time-out machanism instead of burning time in a loop.

Comment: Most likely there is no problem, you probably don't understand your own code. Try changing it to `if(random1 == 1){ printf("abcd"); } else { printf("oops there was no bug after all"); }`. If that fails, debug and single step.

Comment: @Zaibis Sorry for my lack of experience, will try to fix it in the future

Comment: @MOehm So that 's why, this is my first time I'm working with timer so I'm a little bit inexperienced on that one. Can you please explain more?

Comment: @Lundin As Moehm explained, it will print out both cases

Comment: @SlashBunny Yeah so there you go, problem solved... next time use a debugger.

Comment: @Lundin Problem is discovered but haven't had a solution though

Answer (score 3):

Your timing logic will evaluate the dice roll many times in seconds that are divisible by 3. Some of these rolls will satisfy your condition and your text will be printed. Because you don't print anyting when the condition is not met an because you always print to the same screen position, you don't notice.

A quick fix is to reset the `start` timer once you have rolled the dice. The program below illustrated that. (It also separates the dice-rolling from the timing logic.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void roll(void)
{
    int r = rand() % 10;

    if (r < 4) {
        printf("%d Hit!\n", r);
    } else {
        printf("%d Miss.\n", r);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    srand(start);

    while (1) {
        time_t now = time(NULL);

        if (difftime(now, start) >= 3) {
            start = time(NULL);
            roll();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a very crude way to do timed events. If you are using an event-driven framework, for example a GUI toolkit, where everything the user does, clicking the mpouse, pressing a key and so on, is an event, you can use timed events where you can set a time-out or an event occurring at certain intervals as in your case. Such solutions are probably better, but platform dependent.

Comment: Very nice organized and nicely explained. Thanks a lot M Oehm! I don't have enough reputation so I can't vote you up :(

Comment: @SlashBunny but I can (so i did it, :) )

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
do {
time(&end);

elapsed = difftime(end, start);
gotoxy(1, 15);
printf("Time elapsed: %.1d\n", elapsed);
if(elapsed == 0) continue;
min = elapsed%3;
if(min == 0){
    random1 = array[rand() % 9];

    printf("%d\n", random1);

            time(&start);

        if(random1 == 1){
            printf("abcd");
        }
}
```

}

It will reinitialize the timer and you will hit your condition after every 3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this post: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-number-generator-in-arbitrary-probability-distribution-fashion/

In the random number, you can keep 0 and 1 with probability 4 and 6.

I think you can tweak the program to work for your case.